# Google Sheet SQL WHERE CLAUSE Syntax

Tags: sql, google-sheets, subquery

I am trying to write a nested query:

```
Query(get all compensation for an Assignment where Assignment ID = query(Get Assignment ID for <Person Name>))
```

Sources Assignments and Compensations are on two different worksheets.

As new to Google's version of SQL, I am trying it step by step. Example file is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X42vXSTRQY4vtqnf9VWhS9tIqGGKmtAXliu3RgQ14NI/edit?usp=sharing).

A14 contains query for getting the Assignment ID.

```
=query(Demographics!A1:AA316,"select B where I LIKE 'Christopher Lee' ORDER BY B LIMIT 1 ")
```

A18 - query to get all compensation using assignment id from cell A15 (result of query on A14)

```
=QUERY(Compensation!A2:F109012,"select sum(B) where year(C) = year(now()) - 4 and A = "&A15&" ")
```

On A21 - I am trying to replace reference to Cell A15 with query from A14.

```
QUERY(Compensation!A2:F109012,"select sum(B) where year(C) = year(now()) - 4 and A = "&query(Demographics!A1:AA316,"select B where I LIKE 'Christopher Lee' ORDER BY B LIMIT 1 ")&" ")
```

I get the error message:

> Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   NO_COLUMN: Assignment_ID

Is it anything to do with the column header I get on my A14 query?

Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have been through this before. Please try:

```
=QUERY(Compensation!A2:F109012,"select sum(B) where year(C) = year(now()) - 4 and A = "&query(Demographics!A1:AA316,"select B where I LIKE 'Christopher Lee' ORDER BY B LIMIT 1 label(B) '' ")&" ")
```

Maybe only Google knows *exactly* why but it is the nature of QUERY that formatting Text or Number is significant (can't be mixed in a single field). With the Header you have a Text entry at the top - above a Number format record.

Comment: Thanks @pnuts. We have been through something similar before. After comparing your query with mine - I have now realized that for the nested query I need to add a blank label.

Comment: Beside Google's own reference, is there any thing else I can refer to with help/tutorials/examples?

Comment: the query is SQL-based formula. Google creates a table in SQL-database, and the table can have one datatype for a column.